# How to automatically restart systemd service that is killed due to OOM

Tags: linux, service, system, systemd

How do I automatically restart a systemd service that is killed due to OOM.

I have added a restart but I am not sure if this would work on OOMs I cannot reproduce the OOM on my local dev box so knowing this works would be helpful.

```
[Service]
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=1s
```

Error:

```
Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
```

Reading the docs https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html looks like the restart happens on unclean exit code and I think status 9 would come under it, but please can someone validate my thinking.

Comment: You may not be able to reliably reproduce death by OOM-killer, but you can reproduce death by `SIGKILL` at will.

Comment: Do note, however, that terminating because of receipt of a signal is not at all the same thing as terminating with a failure (non-zero) exit status, though *the shell*, when it is involved, will translate the former into the latter.

Comment: Am I wrong to think that in this case the shell will transform the signal to a code and hence my service will restart?

Comment: Also, how do I send SIGKILL and test it?

Comment: Systemd does not use the shell to start service executables, though you can configure an execution of the shell, with appropriate arguments, to *be* the executable for a given service.  So no, generally speaking, the shell is not relevant to the question.  But the systemd docs for the `Restart` parameter directly address the question of when termination due to a signal will cause the service to be restarted.

Comment: With sufficient privilege, you can send any signal to any process via the `kill` command.  It's a bit misnamed, though, as the signal it sends by default is `SIGTERM` not `SIGKILL`.

Comment: From the tag: systemd questions should be for *programming questions* using systemd or its libraries. Questions about *configuring the daemon* (including writing unit files) are better directed to Unix & Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com. Please delete this.

Answer (score 4):

When a process terminates, the nature of its termination is made available to its parent process of record.  For services started by systemd, the parent is systemd.

The available alternatives that can be reported are termination because of a signal (and which) or normal termination (and the accompanying exit status).  By "normal" I mean the complement of "killed by a signal", *not* necessarily "clean" or "successful".

The system interfaces for process management do not provide any other options, but systemd also itself provides for applying a timeout to or using a watchdog timer with services it manages, which can lead to service termination on account of one of those expiring (as systemd accounts it).

The systemd documentation of [the behavior of the various `Restart` settings](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Restart=) provides pretty good detail on which termination circumstances lead to restart with which `Restart` settings.  Termination because of a `SIGKILL` is what the message presented in the question shows, and this would fall into the "unclean signal" category, as systemd defines that.  Thus, following the docs, configuring a service's `Restart` property to be any of `always`, `on-failure`, `on-abnormal`, or `on-abort` would result in systemd automatically restarting that service if it terminates because of a `SIGKILL`.

Most of those options will also produce automatic restarts under other circumstances as well, but `on-abort` will yield automatic restarts *only* in the event of termination because of unclean signal.  (Note that although systemd considers`SIGKILL` unclean, it considers `SIGTERM` clean.)